# python beautiful soup get Chinese immediately after class tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting the Chinese text immediately after this class tag. I've looked at samples and this is the code so far. I'm not sure what to do with my `div` variable. `print div` gives me a blank

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'http://sbj.speiyou.com/search/index/subject:/grade:12/gtype:time'
r = requests.get(page)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

div = soup.findAll('div', {"class" : 'pagination mtop40'})
print div
```

i've tried `print div` , `print div.text` `print div.string` `print div[0]`

Comment: findAll gives you a array of div, you should use div[1],div[2] etc

Comment: I get some input like:`[<div class="pagination mtop40"> 当前第1/17 ..Too Long.... 尾页</a> </div>]`

Comment: so how do i get the text out of it?

Comment: `print div[1].text
IndexError: list index out of range` sorry... this is the error. `print div[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one such tag; so use `soup.find()`, not `soup.findAll()`:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_='pagination')
```

There are both text elements and tags contained; to get the first piece of text, use the [`.strings` or `.stripped_strings` iterables](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings); I'd prefer the stripped variant:

```
print next(div.stripped_strings, u'')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> page = 'http://sbj.speiyou.com/search/index/subject:/grade:12/gtype:time'
>>> r = requests.get(page)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> div = soup.find('div', class_='pagination')
>>> div
<div class="pagination mtop40">
                     当前第1/17页 【 首页 】 <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">1</span>  <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:2">2</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:3">3</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:4">4</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:5">5</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:6">6</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:7">7</a> <a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:8">8</a><a href="/search/index/grade:12/level:/subject:/gtype:time/service:/time:/term:/period:/o:da/bg:n/curpage:17">尾页</a> </div>

>>> print next(div.stripped_strings, u'')
当前第1/17页 【 首页 】
```

Note that there is no need to set `r.encoding` for that page; the server provides you the encoding in the `Content-Type` header anyway.

Comment: `print next(div.stripped_strings, u'')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stripped_strings'` It seems like div keeps returning the empty set

Comment: @jason_cant_code: I used the URL you gave, using `requests`; the `find` call for that class most certainly returns an object. Perhaps you got the wrong page loaded?

Comment: `print div` returns `none` for me for some reason. Could it be there is some anti-scrapping mechanism to the website?

Comment: in fact `grade:10` `grade:11` all also returns `none` ... sigh... weird

Comment: if I `print soup` i see a whole bunch of stuff... so the page was fetched. must be in the `div = soup.find('div', class_='pagination')` statement. Actually when i look thru the `print soup`, `pagination` is not there. Neither can I find `mtop40`.

Comment: @jason_cant_code: do you have `lxml` installed perhaps? It'll be used automatically when installed, but I've seen certain versions fail to parse much of any HTML, leading to just that type of error. Try `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')` instead.

Comment: ah! that did the trick, but I do have lxml installed. I can `import lxml`. I just installed it. so it is a fairly recent version.

Comment: @jason_cant_code: it is the underlying `libxml2` library that is at fault, not `lxml` itself.

Comment: I see, so i should install `libxml2`? I thought i downloaded a version of lxml that included the libxml2 library

Comment: I've seen this plenty of times when answering BeautifulSoup questions here on Stack Overflow, I've not had to troubleshoot it directly. It depends on your OS how and what libraries are installed. But it's never the `lxml` version, always the `libxml2` library that appears to be at fault, yes.